# $ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(\sin{n})\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}}{(\log n)^2}$ is convergent or not

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

> Determine if $ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(\sin{n})\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}}{(\log n)^2}$ is convergent or divergent.

---

[My attempt]

It seems like Dirichlet test, so I tried to show that $a_n := \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}}{(\log n)^2}$ is decreasing and converges to zero.

By the [integral test proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence), I  know that
$$
\int_1^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x}\leq\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\leq 1+\int_1^{n}\frac{dx}{x}
$$
Since $\int\frac{dx}{x}=\ln(x)+C$, I can calculate that $a_n$ converges to zero by the squeeze theorem.

However, I can't show that $a_n$ is a monotonic decreasing sequence...

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}}{(\log{n})^2} \ \ \lor \ \ \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k}}{(\log{(n+1)})^2}$$

$$ \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}\right) \log^2(n+1) - \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k}\right) \log^2(n)   \ \ \lor \ \  0$$

$$ \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}\right) \left[\log^2(n+1) - \log^2(n)\right] - \frac{1}{n+1} \log^2(n)   > \\
\{\log^2(n+1) - \log^2(n) > 0\ \ \text{for} \ \ n > 1 \} \\
\log(n+1) \left[\log^2(n+1) - \log^2(n)\right] - \frac{1}{n+1} \log^2(n) > 0
$$

Last inequality flows from [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln%28x%2B1%29%28ln%28x%2B1%29%5E2+-+ln%28x%29%5E2%29+-+%28ln%28x%29%5E2%29%2F%28x%2B1%29+%3E+0), but I'm not sure, how to prove it strictly. Any help with it?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$a_n = \dfrac{\sum _{k=1}^{n}1/k}{[log (n)]^2}.$$ It can be proved that,

$$\sum _{k=1}^{n}1/k = log(n) + \gamma + o(1)$$, where $\gamma$- Euler's constant. 
Using this, we can simplify $a_n$ so that,

$a_n = 1/log (n) + \gamma/[log(n)]^2+o(1)$. Differentiate this w.r.t $n$ so that $a_n' \leq0$. Hence, the sequence {$a_n$} is non-increasing. Finally, apply the Dirichlet's test to conclude the series is convergent.